# How to retrieve all possible configuration for any maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In pom.xml there is a section of configuration for a specified maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
                ...
                <configuration>
                    <param1>true</param1>
                    ...
                    <param10>value</param1>
                </configuration>
</plugn>
```

How to retrieve all possible params and there restriction for values for the specified plugin? In other words, I need to retrive names for param1, param2... param10.

I have IntelliJ and it hasn't hints for this.

At present time I go to the Internet and read documentation for the plugin. But I think, it isn't the best choice.

Comment: Usually plugin should have a generated site which contains the documentation of the parameters etc. But it's up to the plugin maintainers which unfortunately often don't follow that standard path...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `help:describe` goal by specifying the `detail` property.

For example to get the full description of the maven compiler plugin :

> mvn help:describe
>   -Dplugin=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin -Ddetail

If you want to have the documentation about only a specific goal of a plugin, you can specify the `goal` property with the goal value.

For example to get the full description of the `compile` goal of the maven compiler plugin :

> mvn help:describe
>   -Dplugin=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin -Dgoal=compile -Ddetail

Here is the official documentation of the describe goal of the the Maven Help plugin :

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html

You can of course get it with the plugin itself :

> mvn help:describe -Dplugin=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin
>   -Ddetail -Dgoal=describe

You will get as output:

```
help:describe
  Description: Displays a list of the attributes for a Maven Plugin and/or
    goals (aka Mojo - Maven plain Old Java Object).
  Implementation: org.apache.maven.plugins.help.DescribeMojo
  Language: java

Available parameters:

artifactId
  User property: artifactId
  The Maven Plugin artifactId to describe.
  Note: Should be used with groupId parameter.

cmd
  User property: cmd
  A Maven command like a single goal or a single phase following the Maven
  command line:
  mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]

detail (Default: false)
  User property: detail
  This flag specifies that a detailed (verbose) list of goal (Mojo)
  information should be given.

goal
  User property: goal
  The goal name of a Mojo to describe within the specified Maven Plugin. If
  this parameter is specified, only the corresponding goal (Mojo) will be
  described, rather than the whole Plugin.

groupId
  User property: groupId
  The Maven Plugin groupId to describe.
  Note: Should be used with artifactId parameter.

medium (Default: true)
  User property: medium
  This flag specifies that a medium list of goal (Mojo) information should
  be given.

minimal (Default: false)
  User property: minimal
  This flag specifies that a minimal list of goal (Mojo) information should
  be given.

output
  User property: output
  Optional parameter to write the output of this help in a given file,
  instead of writing to the console.
  Note: Could be a relative path.

plugin
  User property: plugin
  The Maven Plugin to describe. This must be specified in one of three
  ways:

  1.  plugin-prefix, i.e. 'help'
  2.  groupId:artifactId, i.e. 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin'
  3.  groupId:artifactId:version, i.e.
    'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.0'

version
  User property: version
  The Maven Plugin version to describe.
  Note: Should be used with groupId/artifactId parameters.
```

And here are some examples of use of it :

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/examples/describe-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

That's an answer if you want to do it programmatically.

This information is stored as meta data in the plugin jar file (annotations and config file). But not as easy because value controls can be implemented in the plugin code.

Nevertheless you should be able to make a program to inspect the plugin jar an extract useful information like parameter name and type.

Look at the Maven API documentation to know where to search the plugin parameters.

As a note, I think the Eclipse ide has auto completion for plugin parameters in pom.xml files, so the code you need should be findable in their source...